# How to use spark ALS for multi-behavior implicit feedback recommendation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I want to use spark ALS for multi-behavior implicit feedback recommendation. There are several kinds of implicit user behavior data, such as browses, carts, deals etc.

I have checked numerous online sources for ALS implicit feedback recommendation, but almost all of them utilized only single source of data, in shopping case, the deal data.

I am wonder if whether only the deal data is needed or utilize all kinds of data for better results?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general purpose, principled way to use ALS with multiple behaviors. Sometimes different behaviors are used to vary implicit ratings -- for example, viewing an item might be worth 0.1, viewing in multiple sessions might be worth 0.3, putting it in a cart 0.5, and a purchase 1.0. But this feels a bit hacky, and doesn't readily provide a way to exploit all the data you might have.

For a more principled approach that scales to handling lots of different features, I would take a look at the [Universal Recommender](http://actionml.com/universal-recommender). Disclaimer: I've never used it, I just think it sounds promising.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you'd better using all deal data and user data. You use ALS to acquire user vector and deal vector, then compute the similarity of deal and user, if the user or deal have no vector, we can't get the similarity for next recommendation.
I had a test for ALS, and used the similarity of user and deal for training my model, it gave me big surprising，the auc follow as :

```
2018-06-05 21:25:28,138 INFO [21:25:28] [58]    test-auc:0.968764   train-auc:0.972966
2018-06-05 21:25:28,442 INFO [21:25:28] [59]    test-auc:0.968865   train-auc:0.973075
```

because I use all the deal and user information to train the model. but rmse is 3.6, maybe I should tune my parameter.

Comment: pearlwang, you should split your answer and your question: leave here fist half with answer and create new question with second half of your text.

Comment: yeah,you are right, I am sorry for my no discipline. when i saw above question, I have the query， thank you